# In-App Guidance in Lightning App

Tags: lightning-apps

Does anyone know a way to get the In-App Guidance working in a Lightning App?

For context, in the In-App Guidance Builder, I navigate to a custom Lightning App via a button but it replaces the Builder with the custom Lightning App.
The button uses the Naviagtion Service (`lightning:navigation`) with

```
{
    type: 'standard__webPage',
    attributes: {
        url: '/c/x.app?action=y')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way -
Setup (Lightning Experience) | enter In-App in Quick Find box then | select In-App Guidance | To create a new walkthrough > click Add | The In-App Guidance Builder opens in a new tab. This is the base to add, preview and edit walkthroughs. It tells you what page you are on, any other in-app guidance on the page and what to do next.

Let's go to the page where you want to add the walkthrough. Suppose Company's Home Page in the Sales App since here users frequently visit.

Lets click add to save our choice. You can make changes to the walkthroughs in the sidebar that appears in the right.

First choose walkthrough. Another sidebar appears on left hand side that shows all the steps in the walkthrough. The purpose of the walkthrough is to show users some common list view features. You can start with the floating prompt because it works for most walkthrough steps. You can choose the top center position. Next add the title and the body. Lets add some short and impactful content. As you type, the prompts shows an instant preview.

Click add step to start working on step 2. Repeat the same steps to add a floating prompt (at the top left).

Please note, you can add up to 10 steps. (Salesforce recommends its better if we have up to 5 steps) so that users complete the walkthrough else it may be that interesting for the user. By chance if you create long walkthrough, better to divide it. Lets add the final step and do some rearrangement.

In the left side bar, we click the up arrow on step3 to make it the new step 2. We can also delete steps from side bar. Save it.

Please note, when you create walkthrough for the first time, a setting windows open to add additional details. You can always open the settings again on click of gear icon in the builder header while editing the walkthrough. Lets add an action link. Because list view is already set up and ready, we can retain the start date, so that the prompt starts appearing today onwards.

Now you can now decide, if the walkthrough should appear only once or recurring. Lets set 2 recurrences, a week apart > Next > If you want to share the walkthrough to certain users, profiles and permissions this way you can restrict to who sees it. Currently, lets allow all profiles, permissions etc to see it. Make sure that the walkthrough is active. Add a name and description so you can easily identify the prompt on the setup page later > Save

Let's preview the prompt by clicking each step in the left side bar and when everything looks good click Done.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMRTd3T3R24